# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext leak

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, memory, memory-leaks

I have written the following code snippet to take screen snapshot:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(animationView.frame.size);
[[window layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But, UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext seems to be leaking. Is this correct?

In Instruments I could not get the exact leak point. In activity monitor I observed that when I switch to the UI that  executes the above code snippet memory increments by some MB. After this point it never decreases.
Does UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext has memory leak? How do I solve this?

### Edit

Instruments analysis
Activity Monitor: shows the memory hike when this line of code is executed; never decreases even after releasing screenshot (UIImage)

Leaks and allocation, Heap Snapshot: Does not show any leak OR this allocation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext memory leak with previews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121120/uigraphicsgetimagefromcurrentimagecontext-memory-leak-with-previews)

Answer (score -1):

You have just created a UIImage with data for your animationView (which could be some MB).  Perhaps you should wrap this functionality in an autorelease pool.

```
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];     
    UIImage* screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //[screenshot retain]; //If you want precise control over when it is released and you will use it later.
    [pool release];
```

Comment: I have not retained 'screenshot'. Do I need to release it then?

Comment: Actually I guess UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext is autoreleased.  Try wrapping it in an autorelease pool.

Comment: I have tried this. But, of no use. When I created screenshot with some dummy image using the call [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:], real memory was decreased in Activity Monitor after its release.

Answer (score -1):

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

/* you code */

CGContextRelease(context);

clear the context when done