# Swift UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I have a centralized method to resize `UIImages`:

```
public extension UIImage {
    public func scaleToSize(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let hasAlpha = true
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))

        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return scaledImage ?? self
    }
}
```

The problem is that `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` creates leaks because it returns an `autorelease UIImage`. Hence, when I want to assign this `UIImage` to a `UIImageView`, I need to wrap the assignation with `autoreleasepool {...}`. The problem is that I have 2000+ calls to `scaleToSize(size:)` in my app... Is there any other way to fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Which iOS version are you targeting ? You can use UIGraphicsImageRenderer in iOS10+

Comment: I am targeting iOS9+, however I will check `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` so I can add it to iOS 10+ devices. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122107/2124535 ? Here's a simple example of `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer#overview

Comment: Yes, the thing is that the `autoreleasepool` has to be outside my centralized method. And I have 2000+ calls to this methods throughout the app. I'm looking for a way to fix the leaks in a centralized method rather than changing my whole code.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Could you explain to me how autorelease works? Why does it have to be outside your scaleToSize method?

Comment: The variable you want to release has to be into your `autoreleasepool`, but my `scaleToSize` method returns the image I want to free, thus `autoreleasepool` will not work from within the method because the image reaches an higher scope.