# Displaying realtime-processed images on iOS with UIImageView causing memory leak

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

In my app, I plan to capture and heavily-process images (with CPU) from camera and displaying them on the screen along with the preview. Currently, I convert the processed the bitmaps into UIImages and display them through a UIImageView by something like

```
UIImage* newUIIMage = [self convertBitmapToUIIMage];
myUIIMageView.image = newUIImage;
```

And there is steady memory leak. When I commented out the second line and replaced it with saving the UIImage to storage, the leak is fully plugged up. When I tested the code in instruments, it seems the leak comes from something like "alligned_malloc" which is not called by me ( I'm sorry that I do not have the screenshots now, coming later). I have tried some codes else where like [(iphone) UIImageView setImage: leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644912/-iphone-uiimageview-setimage-leaks) but it seems out-dated and the methods like "release" and "autorelease" are not callable.

Any explanations and suggestions? I have full control of the pixels so it is fine if I have to use a different approach to display the images. Much appreciated!

Comment: In any case, here is brute fix: display a deep copy of the UIImage by changing the code to 
UIImage* newUIImage = [self convertBitmapToUIIMage];
UIImage newUIImageDeepCopy = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[newUIImage CGImage]];
myUIIMageView.image = newUIImageDeepCopy;